# SendActivity issue with msteams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a chatbot with botframework.which has been deployed to teams channel.
In the microsoft teams app, my bot keeps typing for a longer time as compared with my webapp.
Any idea why that happens?

Code being used-

```
 await stepContext.context.sendActivity({
                    type: 'typing'
                });
```

Screenshot attached for reference.(The bot keeps typing even after intended reply has been received which doesnt happen in the case of webapp)

[image]

Comment: We could not repro the issue on our side. Could you please share your app manifest with us?

Comment: This may be more of a workaround than a fix, but consider moving the typing activity being sent to the `onMessage()` activity handler. In this way it will occur after every bot activity (you can filter on which so it's not _every_ activity). Suggesting this in case its inclusion in a waterfall step is the cause. Some following activity/step may inadvertently be extending the amount of time the typing activity is displaying.

Comment: is there any other workaround ? to send typing activity instead of sendactivity. IN Bot framework v4

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the recommended method (reference docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#send-a-typing-indicator)). There is `showTypingMiddleware()` that is in the SDK, but it has issues at this time and can't be considered reliable.